# Any bettter way to achieve this lookup table?

Tags: c++, c++11, lookup

***What I need***:

I need a lookup table. Once the keywords are all found, then the value of the `std::unordered_map` is returned.And I don't care about the sequence of the strings in the `std::vector`.

I think `std::unordered_map<std::vector<std::string>, int>` could achieve this goal. Any better method to achieve this goal? Or any improvement for [this code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/cqPd4c8jr)?

````
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Hash
{
    public:
        std::size_t operator()(const std::vector<std::string>& vec) const
        {
            std::hash<std::string> hasher;

            std::size_t hash_value{};
            for(auto itr = vec.begin(); itr!=vec.end(); itr++)
            {
                hash_value ^= (hasher(*itr));  //Why `hash_value ^= ((hasher(*itr))<<1);` does not influence the output of mp.find(to_search)
            }

            return hash_value;
        }
};

class Equal
{
    public:

        bool operator()(const std::vector<std::string>& vec1, const std::vector<std::string>& vec2) const
        {
            bool ret = true;

            if(vec1.size() != vec2.size())
            {
                ret = false;
            }
            else
            {
                for(auto itr_outer = vec1.begin(); itr_outer!=vec1.end(); itr_outer++)
                {
                    bool found = false;
                    for(auto itr_inner = vec1.begin(); itr_inner!=vec2.end(); itr_inner++)
                    {
                        if(*itr_outer == *itr_inner)
                        {
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if(!found)
                    {
                        ret = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return ret;
        }
};

int main()
{
   const std::unordered_map<std::vector<std::string>, int, Hash, Equal> mp = {
        {{"hello word"}, 1},
        {{"thanks a lot", "I need some help"}, 2},
        {{"how to make it better"}, 3},
  };
  
  std::vector<std::string> to_search = {"I need some help", "thanks a lot"};

  auto itr = mp.find(to_search);
  if(itr!=mp.end())
  {
    std::cout <<"found:" << itr->second << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
      std::cout << "not found" << std::endl;
  }
}
```
````

Comment: It might be faster to use a `std::unordered_set` instead of a vector; lookup is faster, and you say you don't care about sequence. If each string exists, and the size is equal, you have equality, as no duplicates can happen.

Comment: @Aganju Thank you for the rapid reply. A question arises after I carefully read your comment.Why `std::unordered_set` is faster, could you please explain that in more detail for me?

Comment: `std::unordered_set` uses a hash to check if a key (here: one of your strings) is inside already. This is faster than looping through the vector and doing a string compare for each element. Note: I meant _inside_ your map - not instead. You would use a `std::unordered_map<std::unordered_set<std::string>,int>`.

Comment: @Aganju I see. Thanks a lot. Then a question arises, how `std::string::operator==()` is implemented? If I understand you correctly, the goal is achieved  by comparing byte one by one other than by comparing hash. But I think it's not the main point, why `std::set` is better for this post is because that it could **avoid to loop through the vector of strings**. Am I right?

Comment: You still have to loop through one of the sets, but yes, not the second one. And the comparison on hash is one instruction, not another loop over all characters. - if you have small amounts, you wouldn't see a performance gain, but for large amounts of data, it should be huge.

Comment: @Aganju Thanks for the guidance. I make a better one, which is seen as the first answer.

Comment: @Aganju After I thought and thought, I found that to achieve a lookup table in this case, there is no need to use `unordered_map` at all. `std::vector<std::pair<std::unordered_set<std::string>, int>>` is much simpler than `std::unordered_map<std::unordered_set<std::string>>`  since the former one doesn't need a custom hash&equal function  at all. For the details, please see the second answer posted by myself. How do you think about it? Looking forward for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you really need. As @Aganju pointed out that looking up a hash is much faster than looping through strings and comparing.

But for your case， you seems to find out whether a specific sentence contains all the keywords or not, in this case hash does not work indeed.  Help that helps.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve a lookup table in this case, there is no need to use `unordered_map` at all. `std::vector<std::pair<std::unordered_set<std::string>, int>>` is much simpler than `std::unordered_map<std::unordered_set<std::string>>` since the former one doesn't need a custom hash function at all.

Here is the [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/8oG8Yc959):

````
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   const std::vector<std::pair<std::unordered_set<std::string>, int>> mp = {
        {{"hello word"}, 1},
        {{"thanks a lot", "I need some help"}, 2},
        {{"how to make it better"}, 3},
  };
  
  std::string str{"Guys, I need some help, thanks a lot!"};

  auto Convert = [&mp](const std::string& str)->int{
        int ret = -1;
        for(auto const& pair:mp)
        {
            bool match = true;
            for(auto const& keyword:pair.first)
            {
                if(str.find(keyword)==std::string::npos)
                {
                    match = false;
                }
            }

            if(match)
            {
                ret = pair.second;
                break;
            }
        }

        return ret;
    };


    std::cout << Convert(str) << std::endl;
    std::cout << Convert("") << std::endl;
    std::cout << Convert("hello") << std::endl;
}

```
````

Comment: While no hashing can be easier, for large amounts there is a price, namely speed: looking up a hash is _much_ faster than looping trough strings and comparing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the guidance of @Aganju. It is faster to use a `std::unordered_set` instead of a vector.

Here is a [better implementation](https://godbolt.org/z/rGzcGMece)(any suggestion is welcome):

````
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>

class Hash
{
    public:
        std::size_t operator()(const std::unordered_set<std::string>& vec) const
        {
            std::hash<std::string> hasher;

            std::size_t hash_value{};
            for(const auto& str:vec)
            {
                hash_value ^= (hasher(str)); 
            }

            return hash_value;
        }
};

class Equal
{
    public:

        bool operator()(const std::unordered_set<std::string>& vec1, const std::unordered_set<std::string>& vec2) const
        {
            bool ret = true;

            if(vec1.size() != vec2.size())
            {
                ret = false;
            }
            else
            {
                bool found = true;
                for(const auto& to_search_str:vec1)
                {
                    if(vec2.find(to_search_str)==vec2.end())
                    {
                        found = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                ret = !found? false:true;
            }

            return ret;
        }
};

int main()
{
   const std::unordered_map<std::unordered_set<std::string>, int, Hash, Equal> mp = {
        {{"hello word"}, 1},
        {{"thanks a lot", "I need some help"}, 2},
        {{"how to make it better"}, 3},
  };
  
  std::unordered_set<std::string> to_search = {"I need some help", "thanks a lot"};

  auto itr = mp.find(to_search);
  if(itr!=mp.end())
  {
    std::cout <<"found:" << itr->second << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
      std::cout << "not found" << std::endl;
  }

  to_search.erase(to_search.begin());
  auto itr1 = mp.find(to_search);
  if(itr1!=mp.end())
  {
    std::cout <<"found:" << itr1->second << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
      std::cout << "not found" << std::endl;
  }
}

```
````

Comment: You do not need `Equal`; `std::unordered_set` already has an `operator==()` that checks if two sets are equal.

Comment: @G.Sliepen I doubt that the said equal provided by default works for `std::unordered_set<std::string>`? You see the hash provided by default does not  suit for `std::unordered_set<std::string>`.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Though I really doubt, but after I did a [test](https://godbolt.org/z/n4Ehx4r9j), I think you are right.Could you please explain that in more detail?

Comment: @G.Sliepen Maybe, there is still some problem indeed. If it's `std::vector<std::string>` other than `std::unordered_set<std::string>`, The default equal would not work any more. See [this](https://godbolt.org/z/frr4hjK93).

Comment: Correct, because order doesn't matter when comparing sets; if two sets contain the same items, they are equal. However, vectors preserve order, so two vectors containing the same items in different orders are not equal.

Comment: @G.Sliepen One more question arises, why there is a default `KeyEqual()` function for `std::unordered_set<std::string>`, whereas there is no default `Hash()` function for `std::unordered_set<std::string>`?

Comment: I have no idea why that is.